# what is the best way to set headers in url in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following bean

```
    public Sample{

    @Value
    private String accoutName;

    @Value
    private String url;

    private String password; //

    @PostConstruct
        public void retrievePassword(){
             String serviceURL = url+ "?accountName=" //I have few more paramaters
             URL obj = new URL(serviceURL);
             HttpsURLConnection connection = null;= (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
             password = readResponse(connection);//inside this i have bufferreader n all

        }
    }

}
```

I fired HTTP request and get the response and store it in the password.

1) How can I make sure this instance variable is secure? I tried to make it final but got the error "Variable password may not have been initialized" This password variable will be accessed from other bean defined in the application context

2) what is the best way to set Headers if i have to set many...I do not want to hardcode. Thanks

Comment: If by "secure" you mean, no other component is able to change it, then you just have to leave it as a private variable and do not create a setter function.

Comment: For the headers question, you should at least provide an example of what you have already tried so other are able to comment out your solution or propose a better approach.

Comment: String serviceURL = url+ "?accountName=" is what i have

Answer (score 0):

There are many unknowns here. But a good start would be as listed below:

1. Password field cannot be final, as you’ll be retrieving value from HTTP call. Better option is to make the field private and provide getters with proper access modifiers.
2. To avoid duplicating HTTP calls, you can create a BaseClass or an UtilityClass which actually makes HTTP call. While invoking this method send your URI and other POST params. And make this an Singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URI builder. Take a look at this example:

```
URI uriBuilder = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost(hostVar)
        .setPath(pathVar)
        .setParameter("parameter1", parameter1Value)
        .setParameter("parameter2", parameter2Value)
        .build();
```

Once you have your URL built, you can get the string value to use it for your HTTP call.

```
String url = uriBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting the headers, you can set a filter and filter mapping in the web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.***.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here, this filter is being invoked for every request (using /*). You can specify any custom path on which you want to invoke the filter.

And create a filter implementation in which you can specify all the headers you want and acceptable request methods as follows:

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Filters CORS request");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        if(!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")||request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE"))){
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "2592000");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type, sessionId, x-token,Set-Cookie,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
            response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "sessionId=" +request.getSession().getId() +"; path=/appname; secure; HttpOnly; domain="+Constants.DOMAINURL);
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "sessionId, x-token");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=2592000");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 2592000000L); // 1 month in future.
            response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().getTime());
            response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            response.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
            response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

            boolean isSendRedirect = false;
            if( !isSendRedirect)
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
          }


        logger.info("Filters CORS request");
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this and got com.mypackage.utils.CorsFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter any reason why i would get this?